# Always fail to connect to DynamoDB in iOS.

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use dynamoDB in my iOS application, but every time I try to connect, I get the following error message.

```
Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=7 "(null)" 
UserInfo={__type=InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException, message=Invalid    
identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.}]
```

I've checked and I get back a cognito ID (which I assume means I'm logged in).  I've setup a federated identity pool for my app (I do not have cognito users).

This is a screenshot of my Auth role (I do not have users or groups).
[image: auth role]

Here is the inline policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
            "cognito-sync:*",
            "cognito-identity:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
             "*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And her is my federated identity pool config

[image]

Comment: If you post your question on Amazon Cognito's forums, we can look into your configuration and better help resolve your issue - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=173

Comment: Done. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=724885&#724885